# Custom keyboard layout not showing in System Preferences in 10.13.6

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, internationalization, customization

I have a custom keyboard layout which I would like to use and I've tried moving the .keylayout file to the /Library/Keyboard Layouts/ and the corresponding directory in home folder, but it doesn't show up in System Preferences app. 
I've also tried having it only in home/Library/Keyboard Layouts/ or only in /Library/Keyboard Layouts/ and both but to no avail.

I would've tried installing it with Ukelele or creating the bundle but Ukelele won't open it saying only that it isn't valid XML. To me it seems to be correct and it was working at one point, but then after restart it disappeared from the System Preferences.

I have tried this already: [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203221)

You can see the .keylayout file here: [Drive DAS Layout](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-sVrpL2Qb33zeZ4zOxw3JR2LOUoV1Pad)

Any help getting this to work is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also ask in the Ukelele group, they are very helpful with such problems:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ukelele-users

Answer (score 1):

A recent [discussion in the Ukelele Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ukelele-users/OykXnDZ4q88) indicates that this problem can be caused by having references to certain illegal characters in the XML file, in particular U+0000 and Unicode [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates).

Comment: I opened your keylayout file and found that many of your keys do point to U+0000, specifically the following ones, in the `keyMap` with `index="2"`: 54–64, 68, 73, 74, 79, 80, 90. There may be other issues, however, as after commenting out those lines, Ukelele still says it's invalid XML.

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder there is also a surrogate dc49 maybe , and it should be xml 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

I found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6778064) that a solution (that worked for me) was to use the Library folder in your user home folder (`~/Library`) as opposed to the root Library folder (`/Library`)

Comment: That did the trick for me, thanks